# How to change NetBeans 7.0 UI font?

Tags: netbeans

& I don't want to break my app...

Have anybody tried:

> "--laf javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel --fontsize 14
>   -J-Dswing.aatext=true -J-Dswing.metalTheme=steel
>   -J-Dswing.plaf.metal.controlFont=Dialog-plain-14" in the
>   netbeans_default_options in Netbean configuration file located at
>   /opt/netbeans/etc/netbeans.conf

?

Answer (score 6):

It works, don't worry about broke the ide you can revert the changes ... ( take a copy of nebeans.conf or just comment with # )

Official Guide:
http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqFontSize

Answer (score -1):

Normally, if I want to change the font in Netbeans, just go to the options menu and then open the "Fonts & Colors" section. Is there a reason you don't want to do that?