# NetBeans: Change Ui's font family

Tags: netbeans, font-family

Sorry for duplicate if my question is it: I found the solution for some hours and tried some solutions, but zero effect or lack of explanations.

So, how I can change the IDE GUI font family? NOT **code** font family, NOT GUI font **size**, changing the the font FAMILY of GUI (menu, labels, etc.), please!!!

It's simply if you use Darcula Look and fill theme, but what if I use the Nimbus light theme?

### Update: Solutions that I tried

Search request: `netbeans change ui font`

Google search results:

1. `Set NetBeans UI Font - plugin detail`

> This module will allow you to set the font family and size of the fonts used by netbeans in the UI. When you add the command line switch -J-Dramos.nb.ui.font="MyFavoriteFont,14" to the netbeans options this module will set the font used by netbeans to the font named MyFavoriteFont with the size of 14. This doesn't seem to work with synth based look and feels.

Where I need to input `-J-Dramos.nb.ui.font="MyFavoriteFont,14"` in NetBeans options??!!

2. `FaqFontSize - NetBeans Wiki`

Not font size, font family please!!

3. How to change NetBeans 7.0 UI font? - [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996634/how-to-change-netbeans-7-0-ui-font)

Contains link to `FaqFontSize - NetBeans Wiki`

4. NetBeans IDE scaling on Windows 8

Not scaling, UI font family change please!!

5. [My Knowledge: How To Change Netbean UI Font](http://johnleemy.blogspot.jp/2006/10/how-to-change-netbean-ui-font.html)

It's about changing font size. Not size, font family, please!!

6. [Netbeans Interface way too small : Surface - Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Surface/comments/3tszg9/netbeans_interface_way_too_small/)

It's about changing font size. Not size, font family, please!!

---

Here is [Japanese article](http://designhack.slashlab.net/netbeans-8-fonts-windows7/), but you can understand what is required to edit in [fontconfig.properties.src](http://designhack.slashlab.net/netbeans-8-fonts-windows7/). Unfortunately, it does not works.

Comment: Please add the question reference which didn't work for you.

Comment: @Ratul Sharker, OK but please wait until I collect all links again.

Comment: don't need to mention that, just mention in the question, what have you tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

> So, how I can change the IDE GUI font family? NOT code font family,
>   NOT GUI font size, changing the the font FAMILY of GUI (menu, labels,
>   etc.)

Unfortunately, the ability to specify the font family for the IDE itself is not currently provided in NetBeans. See these NetBeans bug reports requesting the same feature:

- [Bug 114017 - I18N - provide properties/options to change ide global font name and font size](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=114017)
- [Bug 125083 - I18N - IDE's Font/Fontsize can be configured furthest](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=125083)

> Where I need to input -J-Dramos.nb.ui.font="MyFavoriteFont,14" in
>   NetBeans options?

To specify the details for the "ramos" plugin you referenced:

- Locate and edit the text file **netbeans.conf** which will be under your NetBeans installation directory in the **etc** folder.
- Locate the line containing the text **netbeans_default_options** and append the data for the plugin, save the file and then restart NetBeans. For example, this line (at the very end) specifies to the plugin that the **Serif** font should be used for the NetBeans IDE:

netbeans_default_options="-J-client -J-Xss2m -J-Xms32m -J-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true -J-Dapple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=true -J-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -J-Dsun.java2d.dpiaware=true -J-Dsun.zip.disableMemoryMapping=true **-J-Dramos.nb.ui.font=Serif,14**"

Here is a screen shot of the NetBeans IDE using that (really ugly!) Serif font:

[image]

If the approach described above does not work for you then select **IDE Log** from NetBean's **View** menu to review startup issues. Any problems with the plugin might be logged there.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! After finding solution for a fer hours I expressed some emotions in my question, so I really thank you for only reading this. I am trying to setup the font yet and will white the comment again.

Comment: I tried `SetFont` plugin for the few times but no effect. I need to find the other way to setup the default font...

Comment: @GurebuBokofu Do you see any error messages in the IDE Log after restarting NetBeans?

Comment: @GurebuBokofu Also, you could try using the Serif font, since that worked for me.