# Netbeans 8.2 scale setting

Tags: java, ubuntu, netbeans

Im looking for a solution for the fact that Netbeans doesn't seem to care about the scale setting of Ubuntu for displaying menus and icons. The screen of my laptop (15") is a high resolution screen (3840x2160) with scale set to 200%. I'm running Ubuntu 17.10 and using Netbeans 8.2 and it looks like this (note the small arrows compared to the text):

[image: screenshot]

Increasing the font-size makes the font readable, but it doesnt change the size of popups and icons. I've tried to set the following setting to false, as suggested in other related topics but this doesn't change anything:

-J-Dsun.java2d.dpiaware

Comment: See my answer to a similar question (How to change the size of the module icon in Netbean) here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47882342/how-to-change-the-size-of-the-module-icon-in-netbean/48071384#48071384

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This solution for windows however does not work on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, all you need is to type this from command line:

> netbeans --fontsize 22

it will work if you have installed netbeans from the repository.

If you downloaded and installed it, you need to:

1. Locate and edit the text file **netbeans.conf** which will be under
   your **NetBeans** installation directory in the **/etc** folder.
2. Locate the line containing the text **netbeans_default_options** and
   append "--fontsize 22"

It should look like this:

> netbeans_default_options="-J-client -J-Xss2m -J-Xms32m
>   -J-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true -J-Dapple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=true -J-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -J-Dsun.java2d.dpiaware=true -J-Dsun.zip.disableMemoryMapping=true --fontsize 22"

22 should work fine but of course you can use the size you prefer

You can set more options here, like font family etc. you can find more info here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47063790/4567313)