# I want to change the font size of the sub-sub-menus and file explorer in Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, configuration, config, netbeans-8

The sub-menus font size can be edited through the config file but the the sub-menu elements that expand into other menus are not affected by this. The config file also does not affect the file explorer.

[The sub-menu example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xxf4.png)

[The file explorer example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Of9C1.png)

Comment: I used an old [NetBeans plugin named **Set NetBeans UI Font**](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/7737/set-netbeans-ui-font) that still worked on NetBeans 8.2. [See my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47063790/2985643) to a similar SO question [NetBeans: Change Ui's font family](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47026901/2985643).

Comment: Also, I don't know what you were setting in **netbeans.conf**, but another approach that will definitely increase the font size in the **Files** panel is to specify **fontsize** as a parameter when starting NetBeans. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/48071384/2985643 and [FaqFontSize](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqFontSize).

Comment: I have tried all of that; the issue still persists; I don't know why my laptop has issues displaying things correctly.

Comment: OK. Do you know the resolution of your laptop screen? Also, could you check the NetBeans log (**View > IDE Log**) and update your question if there are any messages related to setting the font size when you start NetBeans.